# assigning location dots to image on processing

Tags: algorithm, processing

I am using processing and have come up with the following code which I am going to use to assign dots on a map image according to the location which is in the "postcodes.csv" image. I am always getting the error `"The constructor Table(String) is undefined"` does anyone know what that means and what I could do to my code to correct this error. I am new to processing and am still learning.

I believe the codes that I am using will work but not very sure if it will work. Can someone please provide me with a better code to enable me to use? The code that I am using is:

```
 PImage mapImage;  
 Table locationTable;  
 int rowCount;  
 void setup( ) {  
 size(388, 600);  
 mapImage = loadImage("UKmap.png");  
 locationTable = new Table("postcodes.csv");      
  rowCount = locationTable.getRowCount( );     
  }     
  void draw( ) {     
   background(255);    
    image(mapImage, 0, 0);     
     smooth( );      
        fill(192, 0, 0);      
       noStroke( );      
      for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++) {     
      float x = locationTable.getFloat(row, 1); // column 1     
     float y = locationTable.getFloat(row, 2); // column 2      
    ellipse(x, y, 9, 9);  
     }    
     }
```

Comment: The is clearly a language-specific question and needs to be tagged as such.

Comment: @Hooked it is, the language is called "Processing". Bad name but good language.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead:

```
locationTable = loadTable("postcodes.csv");
```

The error message you got means that you can't create directly a Table object from a String object. However there is this function `loadTable` that loads, parses the CSV file and returns a Table object with the corresponding contents.